# Can't parse selenium python flashscore

Tags: python, selenium

I'm sorry guys my brain is buffering in this problem since a lot of time. I'm trying to get all match summary deatails: results and date. I'm parsing it filtering the 0-0 score.
Now what I want is to get the match if in the 5 last match team 1, last 5 match team 2 and h2h btw them there is minimum 1 goal. If there is one 0-0 result match i don't get anything.
For now i'm stacked here:

```
driver.get("[https://www.flashscore.com/match/KIhcwU8b/#h2h/overall][1]")
results = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='h2h__regularTimeResult' and not(text()='0 : 0')]")))]
dates = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='h2h__regularTimeResult' and not(text()='0 : 0')]//ancestor::div[1]/span[@class='h2h__date']")))]
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='h2h__row']")


for i,j in zip(results, dates):
    print(f"{i} result was on {j}")
```

How to put the if condition inside the for? I tried everything but nothing worked for now.
Thank yuou a lot guys.

I mean i want to get first 5 matches with results of team 1, team 2, and h2h btw them. And if there is  a 0-0 in the score i won't get it.
This is example page of flashscore overall.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRQ3S.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRQ3S.png)

Comment: maybe first get all scores and later filter it in Python code.

Comment: maybe you sholdn't get it as two separated `for`-loops but use one normal `for`-loop and seach `result` and `date` in one loop. And then you can simply add `if`-condition.

Comment: you could create minimal working code (with imports, etc) so we could simply copy and run code. You could also show what you get and what result you exactly expect for curent page.

Comment: I added an example of the page yea. I miss only the if condition.

Comment: you should add also expected result for this page. But I think you should create one normal for-loop instead of two `list comprehensions` and then you can simply add `if`-condition,. or you can use some variable to count results and use `break` to exit after 5th result.

Comment: Or maybe you should simply use `zip(results, dates)[:5]` or `zip(results[:5], dates[:5])` to get only first 5 matches.

Comment: Thank you i will try furas. And how to get first 5 matches for each section? I mean get first 5 matches for team 1, team 2 and h2h. How?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to get. As I said before: better show in question what exactly result you expect for data on this page.

Comment: If you open the url link of the image you could understand. In the overall match summary page there are 3 sections: Last matches team 1, Last matches team2, h2h. My question is: how I can get 5 match for each of them? And if there is 0:0 in one of those results i won't get anything. This is the result that I excpect.

Comment: I already opened page before first comment and I still don't understand what you want to do. And I will repeate: better show exactly expected result instead of describe it. If you want 5th matches which have result different then `0 : 0` then you have all in previous comments - ie. `zip(results, dates)[:5]` or `zip(results[:5], dates[:5])`

Comment: OK, I think now I understand - If every section has 5 results then you can get all results and split them using `[:5]`, `[5:10]`, `[10:]` and later remove results `0 : 0`. But if every section may have different number of results then you will have to read row after row (even with headers) and detect where is header to detect where starts every section.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand what you want to do but I would use one normal `for`-loop instead of two separated `list comprehensions` and then I could use more complex code inside `for`-loop. I could use some variable to count result different then `0 : 0` and I could use `break` after 5th result.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://www.flashscore.com/match/KIhcwU8b/#h2h/overall"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(3)

all_rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='h2h__row']")
print('len(all_rows):', len(all_rows))

count = 0
for row in all_rows:
    date   = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='h2h__date']").text
    result = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='h2h__regularTimeResult']").text
    team_home = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'h2h__homeParticipant')]").text
    team_away = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'h2h__awayParticipant')]").text
    if result != '0 : 0':
        count += 1
        print(f"{date} | {result} | {team_home:20} | {team_away}")
    if count == 5:
        break
```

Result:

```
len(all_rows): 15

23.11.21 | 1 : 0 | Tigre                | Barracas Central
15.11.21 | 1 : 3 | Villa Dalmine        | Barracas Central
07.11.21 | 3 : 0 | Barracas Central     | San Martin S.J.
31.10.21 | 1 : 2 | Brown Adrogue        | Barracas Central
29.11.21 | 1 : 0 | Almirante Brown      | Ind. Rivadavia
```

---

**EDIT:**

If every section has 5 results then you can get all results and split using `[0:5]`, `[5:10]`, `[10:15]` (or using for loop using `[i:i+5]`) and later skip results with `0 : 0`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://www.flashscore.com/match/KIhcwU8b/#h2h/overall"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(3)

all_rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='h2h__row']")
print('len(all_rows):', len(all_rows))

for i in range(0, 15, 5):
    print('--- section ---')
    for row in all_rows[i:i+5]:
        date   = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='h2h__date']").text
        result = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='h2h__regularTimeResult']").text
        team_home = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'h2h__homeParticipant')]").text
        team_away = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'h2h__awayParticipant')]").text
        if result != '0 : 0':
            print(f"{date} | {result} | {team_home:20} | {team_away}")
```

Result:

```
len(all_rows): 15
--- section ---
23.11.21 | 1 : 0 | Tigre                | Barracas Central
15.11.21 | 1 : 3 | Villa Dalmine        | Barracas Central
07.11.21 | 3 : 0 | Barracas Central     | San Martin S.J.
31.10.21 | 1 : 2 | Brown Adrogue        | Barracas Central
--- section ---
29.11.21 | 1 : 0 | Almirante Brown      | Ind. Rivadavia
22.11.21 | 1 : 1 | Ind. Rivadavia       | Almirante Brown
15.11.21 | 3 : 2 | Almirante Brown      | Alvarado
07.11.21 | 3 : 1 | Tigre                | Almirante Brown
--- section ---
31.01.19 | 3 : 1 | Barracas Central     | Almirante Brown
25.08.18 | 1 : 0 | Almirante Brown      | Barracas Central
19.03.18 | 3 : 1 | Barracas Central     | Almirante Brown
```

---

Or you should find `@class='h2h__section section` and work with every section separatelly.

This can be useful if first you want to click buttons `"Show more matches"` to get more results.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://www.flashscore.com/match/KIhcwU8b/#h2h/overall"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(3)

# --- show more results in every section --

for i in range(3):
    # after every click search all elements again
    section_more_results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='h2h__section section ']//div[@class='h2h__showMore showMore']")
    print('len(section_more_results):', len(section_more_results))
    print('click:', i)
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', section_more_results[i])
    # it needs to move to this element because it is hidden
    #section_more_results[i].click()

# --- get resulst in every section ---
        
all_sections = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='h2h__section section ']")

for section in all_sections:
    all_rows = section.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='h2h__row']")
    print('--- section ---')
    print('len(all_rows):', len(all_rows))
    count = 0
    for row in all_rows:
        date   = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='h2h__date']").text
        result = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='h2h__regularTimeResult']").text
        team_home = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'h2h__homeParticipant')]").text
        team_away = row.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'h2h__awayParticipant')]").text
        if result != '0 : 0':
            print(f"{date} | {result} | {team_home:20} | {team_away}")
            count += 1
        if count == 5:
            break
```

Comment: Yea this is what i was looking for. One more thing if you could help me. Now from this base how to parse it more? I mean I want to get first 5 matches from the team home, first 5 matches from team away and 5 matches from h2h. Then if there is 0:0 will filter it like you have done now.

Comment: I updated the image url to help you understand.

Comment: I added new examples. Last example first search sections and later work with every section separatelly.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the waste of time doing it. From this base I will separate everything and if there is a 0:0 in one of the 3 section all the loop will return nothing because I want to get only the matches with min. 1 goal per match. THanks a lot.

Comment: Cna you help me to count the 0-0 results in all 3 section? Even if I put the c=0 outside the for it only takes the 0-0 result matches from the last section not from all 3. How to do it?

Comment: if you want to count total for all section then you have to put `c` before first `for`-loop. If you want to count for every section separatelly then you need list `c = [0, 0, 0]` and later use index to increase correct value `c[index] += 1`. Or you can use dictionary `c = {section_1_name: 0, section_2_name: 0, section_3_name: 0}`  and use section name to count it `c[section_name] += 1`. Eventually you could use special dictionary `c = collections.Counter()` instead of standard dictionary

Comment: I was trying to do the same thing and I added the c=0 in the top before all the for's and trying to do this: if result != '0 : 0': count+=1 else: c=c+1 but it always count only the last section. Why?

Comment: Code example: https://ibb.co/c2RZqMk

Comment: you have wrong indentations. `for row in all_rows:` has to be inside `for section in all_sections:` but you have different indentations and you have it outside - and this change everything. It runs `for row in all_rows:` only for last section. See indentations in my answer.

Comment: Yea I fixed it already before your answer thank you a lot. Now I have the last problem. I'm trying to put an if condition in the for i range (3) so if there is no 7 match for every section then the program will print only "NOT OK" or something like that. Code example: https://ibb.co/0sgzzXY. In less words if the match summary has not 7 matches for each section then is not good so I print the same thing as the if condition if you can see. I was trying to do it at the for i in range 3 loop but it's not efficent. Any suggestions?

Comment: if you want to check it for evey section separatelly then you have to do it inside `for section ...` but you do it after `for section ...` - so you again have wrong indentations. And it may need to check `if count < 7:` instead of `if c >= 1:`

Comment: No i fixed the indentation of all the script. The thing is I thought the same thing but it's not working. It gives me an error before the "for section.." list out of index in the "for i in range 3" in that loop. Example here: https://ibb.co/VHmyhmS. This is the last thing I should do in this script.

Comment: image shows that last section doesn't have `Show more` - so there are only 2 instead of 3 links to click - so you have to check `i < len(section_more_results)` before you click.

Comment: Img: https://ibb.co/PDJDT6N. As you can see the last id match has only 2 sections with 7+ matches, last one has only 1 match so the program shouldn't print OK but NOT OK. I put the i < len(section_more_results) and the other if but nothing. Am I going on the wrong way?

Comment: if you have new problem then better create new question on new page - Stackoverflow is not forum and we should resolve new problems in comments. And send code as text. We can't copy code from image to use it for test.

Comment: you still have the same mistake - you have wrong indentations. You have `if c >= 1:` after `for section ...` so it can display only for last section. It has to be inside `for section ...` to display for all sections. So you had two problems - first `i < len(section_more_results)` and second  `if c >= 1:`

Comment: now I see other problem - you use `i < len(section_more_results)` in wrong way. You run `break` but you should run `execute_script`: - `if i < len(section_more_results): driver.execute_script(...)`. But I think in some situations it may need more complex code. It may need to get every section separatelly and check if it has `Show more` to click it.

Comment: Exactly this is what I was looking for. Check for every section separatelly if it has 3 Show more to click then it continue to parsing the match. If not then he pass the id printing something and going on the next element so. Do you have some idea?

Comment: No the indentation is right of the "if c>=1" because in this way it takes under control all the 3 section and it goes +1 if there is a 0-0 match in each one of them. Without controlling every section separatelly because it's useless can we do another thing? I mean if there is no section click in 1 of the 3 section then he pass to next element. In this way if there isn't it's ok but if there are 3 section to click it check below then if every section has min. 7 matches for everyone. Is it right?